# Running Dll Contains MFC Class in other computer C++

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I've made a normal dll (not a MFC dll) and I use there CImage Class (MFC) and it works great.
First of all I dont have lot of experience in dlls, so I wonder how my dll works if i didn't used the "MFC Dll" option, and whats the difference between the two options.

My second question is if the fact that I am using the CImage class (MFC) can make problems if I run my dll on some other computers with windows operation system or there will be no problem running it on every computer with windows operation system?

I think that if I am using the CImage class my dll's size will grow due to the additional classes that is being added (by the way, it adds all the MFC classes or only the CImage one?)
and therefore I don't relay on the computer that run my dll, but I am not sure at all.

Thank you for the time and the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC DLL is more a DLL wizard that sets some boilerplate code for you if you are going to follow the MFC framework usage guidelines. It is not absolutely necessary to be able to use MFC. You may still create your own code and use it as you wish.

As it comes to MFC cross-machine portability, it is transparent when you link to MFC statically (default setting in Release build) but you should ensure that the corresponding MFC dll library is present on the target machine if you link to MFC dynamically (Debug build).

While MFC is a quite big framework with its good and bad sides using its single, separate features is not a common practice and maybe you should consider other solution like http://openil.sourceforge.net for handling images without all the burden of a framework.

Comment: I didn't understand the part of the MFC cross-machine portability.

Comment: What is the meaning of link to MFC Statically or Dynamically?
and I dont know well whats the Release build and Debug build are.

What do you mean by saying "the corresponding MFC dll library"? I have no idea about the lib that the CImage using (not written here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5(v=vs.80).aspx)

thanks and please reply so I can know if the dll can work on every computer with windows operation system.

Comment: Cross-machne means using the dll on a computer where it was not originally built. When building a project you usually see two configurations: Debug and Release. Debug build creates by default a dependency on the DLL containing the MFC library (dynamic linking) so it expects that DLL to be present while being run. On the other hand Release build uses the static version of the MFC library ensuring that all necessary code is inside the dll you are building. You may explore the options of the project you created to build the dll.

Comment: ok now I understand much more! so I should build my Project as Release build. In order to do that I need to change the Solution Configuration near the "Start Debugging" to "Release" and than click on Build Solution?

Comment: Yes, it will build your project with settings optimized for distribution like static MFC linking. The target binary should be located in Release subdirectory of your project's directory.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "The target binary"?

Comment: The physical dll file you are building with given configuration (Debug or Release)